# Tensorflow stuck at tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 256 to 281

Tags: gpu, tensorflow

I’m running a Tensorflow code, which’s always gets stuck at this point:

tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 256 to 281

I tried different memory configuration but none worked.

The code never fails but never progress from there so I end up cancelling the job. I'm running it on Tesla K40m with 4 CPUs each with 16G of memory.

Here is the full output:

```
2017-11-10 17:00:15.091618: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-10 17:00:15.091997: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-10 17:00:15.092010: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-11-10 17:00:17.609926: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:940] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: Tesla K40m
major: 3 minor: 5 memoryClockRate (GHz) 0.745
pciBusID 0000:0d:00.0
Total memory: 11.17GiB
Free memory: 11.09GiB
2017-11-10 17:00:17.609969: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:961] DMA: 0 
2017-11-10 17:00:17.609979: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] 0:   Y 
2017-11-10 17:00:17.609994: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1030] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla K40m, pci bus id: 0000:0d:00.0)
2017-11-10 17:00:39.678955: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 1787 get requests, put_count=1575 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.634921 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.734191
2017-11-10 17:00:39.679428: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 100 to 110
2017-11-10 17:01:25.550744: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:247] PoolAllocator: After 2416 get requests, put_count=2444 evicted_count=1000 eviction_rate=0.409165 and unsatisfied allocation rate=0.411838
2017-11-10 17:01:25.551299: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.cc:259] Raising pool_size_limit_ from 256 to 281
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 5538559 ON dgpu501-26-r CANCELLED AT 2017-11-10T17:47:10 ***
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have code which reproduces (presumably just up to the point of creating a session)? Happy to take a look.

Comment: @AllenLavoie I'm sorry, I don't understand what do you mean